# Vertica Python Unable to Connect

Tags: python, database-connection, vertica

I'm trying to use the vertica_python module at https://github.com/vertica/vertica-python to connect to my corporate vertica database. My code looks like:

```
from pytrends.request import TrendReq
import pandas as pd
import vertica_python

conn_info = {'host': '127.0.0.1', 'port': 5433, 'database': '*****',
    'user': '*****', 'password': '*****'}
connection = vertica_python.connect(**conn_info)
```

Firstly, what does the host parameter mean? Is it supposed to be my machine's IP, the database IP, the database URL, or something else entirely?

Secondly, I keep getting the error:

> vertica_python.errors.ConnectionError: Failed to establish a connection to the primary server or any backup address

Has anyone had experience resolving this in the past? How did you go about it?

Answer (score 1):

`host` is the name or the IP address of a Vertica node; `database` is the name of the database; `user` is the login user; `password` is what it says.

Answer (score 0):

The connection timeout is probably because the machine you are accessing the vertica cluster from does not have access to the production server the cluster sits in. Are you accessing from a non-prod environement or a local machine that sits in the corporate vpn? Either way your infosec team has probably blocked the connection.

You can test the traffic by identifying the IP address of the vertica cluster using `SELECT node_address FROM nodes` and using `PING node_address`. If no packets are recieved, there is a connectivity issue from your ip and you should discuss with your devops and infosec for a different solution to use verticaPy